# What is the best way to check if ALL values in a range exist in an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, range

How do I test that an array contains at least once, every integer value from 1 to 3? 
for example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int array[7] = {2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 1};
  if (/* array contains 1, 2 and 3 */) {
    printf("TRUE\n");
  } else {
    printf("FALSE\n");
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Your options are to use O(N) extra space with O(N) time complexity, or O(logN) extra space with O(NlogN) time complexity. Choose wisely.

Comment: It can be done in O(N+M) time and O(M) extra space, where N is the length of the array and M the length of the range. You just use counting sort, except you don't sort, just check all values are greater than 0.

Comment: There's also a happy case to check in constant time: array needs to be at least as long as the range to contain all elements in the range.

Comment: Also, could you (the one who asked the question) rephrase? What's "best" is ambiguous. It could be the most straightforward and easy to read, it could be the faster, or the lighter in terms of memory use. There's no single best solution that fits all. That's a general fact of life.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to decide how to specify the range you want. For instance, do you want to enumerate each value or do you simply want to specify the minimum and maximum values?

For instance, if you only want to use contiguous values then specifying the minimum and maximum values will be satisfactory. On the other hand, if you want to specify the first eight even numbers, or the first ten prime numbers, then a minimum and maximum value are not as much help, and an enumerated list may be more useful.

Consider defining a struct containing a single value in the value series you want to identify along with a count of the occurrences of that value. Construct an array of those structs sufficiently large to represent each value in your value series.

Now iterate through the array you want to study. Compare each array value with values in your array of structs. If it matches a value increment the corresponding count.

After examining each value in the array you want to study examine the array of structs. If all the counts in the array of struct are greater than 0 your original array contains at least one instance of every value in the series. If one or more of the counts is 0 then one or more of the values is missing from the array you want to study.

Comment: You could also create a quick early check. If the size of the array to study is smaller than the sequence you want to verify then some value or values are missing.

Comment: Also note that, if the range is not continuous, you can use a binary search to find the referred element, instead of iterating the range array. As long as those are sorted, of course, and that it make sense (a binary search for 10 elements is nonsense).

Answer (score 0):

what do you think of this ?
Basically, you create an array with the values you want to find in your array.
You create a function to do that and you send your array and the values you want to find in it.
Also send the size of each array to avoid errors.
Then for each value you try to find, iterate on the array to find it.
If you go threw the whole array without finding it, return false cause your value is not inside your array.
If you never return false in your for loop, it means you always found the value, therefore you can return true. All your values are inside the array.

```
bool   areValuesInArray(int *array, int *value, int sizeArray, int sizeValue)
{
    int j;
    for (int i = 0, i < sizeValue; i++)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j < sizeArray && array[j] != values[i])
             j++;
        if (j == sizeArray)
             return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You could even do this with a linked list, so each time you find an element, you remove it from the list, thus having fewer elements to iterate the next time. You can allocate the list in a continuous array for efficiency.

Comment: You might not want to modify any of the array or lists here I think. And doing copy would not be optimal

Comment: I did miss that, I assumed the program created it from a continuous range (a pair of integers). On efficiency, it depends. Doing a copy adds `sizeValue` `int`s of memory and `sizeValue` iterations, but at the same time it can remove many checks per element in `array`, and if `sizeArray` is much larger than `sizeValue` that will most likely have more weight.

Comment: Besides, removing elements make it possible to recheck for size and return early if there aren't enough remaining elements in `array` to contain the remaining elements in `value`.

Answer (score -1):

there are 2 ways, either use the map function to check for all the 3 variables, but the issue is this might take longer with lot of data

so probably you can use the includes method.

so it becomes `array.includes(1)`.This returns a boolean.

Comment: Hi Krishna, welcome! You're thinking about the wrong language. C doesn't have methods (you can simulate them, though), and doesn't have a map function (unless you implement it or use a library). Besides, I think the 3 values `1`, `2` and `3` are just an example input.